# Apache camel : how to handle exception outside routing engine at file producing end point

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route like below in my application -

From("sftp:config").to("file:config")

I have to handle those exceptions which occurs outaide the default exception handling boundary of apache camel in producing endpoint. E. G. Exception may occur at the time of writing the file. How can i handle that exception?

In camel documentation, i read that for file consumer they have provided different options like - consumer.errorHandler and consumer.bridgeErrorHandler. But there is no option for file producer (like producer.errorHandler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camel's file component uses the Java file API to write the file, so in case of any error then Java API should report that as an error (either using an exception) or returning true|false in some of its api.

If either of that happens then Camel file component (producer) should detect this and wrap that as an exception, that the error handler should be able to react upon.

It may be that depending on which file system / JDK / platform you are using it may behave a bit different. See the file api / javadoc etc.

You do not provide much detail what happens etc. But the answer is that out of the box, Camel's error handler is included on the producer side.

On the consumer side, its a bit different story, see more about the bridge error handler option.

Answer (score 0):

This will be not exactly suitable answer for this question. But, it would be helpful to someone who are looking to cancel entire process when one event is throwing error/exception out of multiple events.

For example, I am travelling from one location to other location which required to use both flight and train. So, I need to book both at a time. If anyone will fail, the entire transaction has to fail. To achieve this use case, author has followed SAGA pattern in Apache camel. For more information, have a look at below link.

[Apache Came with Saga](https://www.nicolaferraro.me/2018/04/25/saga-pattern-in-apache-camel/)